# How do I move text from a file into a text area?

Tags: java, file, jtextarea

In this code:

```
protected void open() {
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(Main.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    }
}
```

How can I get the contents of `file` and set it to a text area called `textarea`?

Comment: Read the file in to a string (trivially searchable), then set the component's text--what isn't working for you?

Comment: Is it specifically a text area you need?  It is quite simple using a `JEditorPane`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the API provided by all Swing text components to read a file. Something like:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader( file );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
textArea.read( br, null );
br.close();
```

Comment: Ooh, nice - didn't know about that. Although you should close it in a finally block :)

Comment: camickr, if the file takes too long, this gonna freeze gui?

Comment: @nachokk, yes I would guess it would.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to read it as text?

If you're happy to use a third-party library, I would personally use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), which makes it trivial:

```
// This is assuming the file is UTF-8. If not, change appropriately.
String text = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
textarea.setText(text);
```

Note that this will load the file in the UI thread, which will hang the UI while it's loading... not nice if it's a very large file, but simpler than delegating to a separate thread.

Comment: +1 for delegating to separate thread, as camickr answer seems better it only runs in the edt.